# Empty collection Anylogic whilst connected with agents

Tags: simulation, anylogic, vehicle-routing

I am trying to create a simulation program for the multi-depot Vehicle routing problem with a heterogeneous fleet. When I create the agents (vehicle, depot and consumer), I connect them to a data base. Upon the creation of the depot and consumer agents, the database values (lattitude and longitude) are connected to the GIS map via GIS latitude and GIS longitude.  The agents are then non-empty using the data from Excel. However, when I try to create a collection to iteratively use the individual agents, the collection remains empty.

[Collection from anylogic as designed now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XggnM.png)

Does anybody know why the collections are empty? How can I solve this?

Comment: this is probably because when you create the collection on time t=0, your agents are not yet created... maybe create the collection with an event after 1 milisecond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collection you created is just saying that it is expecting objects of type Consumer. So it is just creating the list not adding anything

One option is to add some code to your agent's On Startup code to add it to the collection upon creation

[image]

Remember that the population object can act as a list, it is iterable and you can access objects by index... so no real need for a separate list.

Comment: Jaco-Ben this is exactly what i needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

A collection is not automatically filled. You will have to fill the collection with a function.

But if you just want to iterate over the agents, you don't need a collection. You can just iterate over the agent population.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).